# Blocked Pokemon Go on Android 6

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to use another old phone to play Pokemon Go, my old phone has Android 6.
I have installed Pokemon Go correctly from the Google play store but it remains blocked to the choose date page, I can't do anything.
I allowed all permission when it asked me.
This phone doesn't have a sim card is that a problem?
If I try to click something nothing happens. 
What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Not having a sim card would mean no mobile data, so you wouldn't be able to do much anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blocked to the choose date page". Does that page not respond? Does it crash?

Comment: @Studoku have wifi near some pokestops and gym so yes I can do something, The page not respond, if I click on the date to insert it nothing happen

Comment: Is the phone rooted?

Comment: @Studoku yes, it's a samsung galaxy nexus(maguro) with twrp and lineage os

Comment: Problem solved- rooted/jailbroken phones are not compatible with pokemon go.

Comment: My other phone (nexus 5) have the same configuration with twrp and lineage 14 and works perfectly

Comment: @Studoku My phone is rooted, and I can play Pokémon just fine. We had a question about helping support apps on unsupported platforms, I thought, but I can't recall the outcome.

Comment: @Wondercricket Yes I had just found that myself. Thought so; we don't mind helping getting a game working on a rooted device. I mean, its not hard to do for android, although I haven't run into this particular issue before.

Answer (score 1):

You need an internet connection to play Pokemon GO. A SIM card gives you easier access via mobile data, but it's not needed. You can also use Wifi or connect to another phone's mobile data with mobile hotspot. Not having a SIM card will not cause this issue, but not having an internet connection will. I recently got to that screen on a phone without a SIM card and proceeded without issues.

Have you tried restarting the Pokemon GO app and reloading it? The app getting frozen or stuck in certain parts of the game is a very common issue, and this regularly solves it.

Comment: Given that the phone managed to download the app from the play store, I imagine the internet connection works.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the comments: Pokemon GO does not support rooted/jailbroken devices.

Answer (score -2):

My phone doesn't have a SIM card yet I can play it, so no, that isn't a problem.

Things you can do that may counter this issue:

- Uninstall and reinstall the app.
- Restart your phone
- Shut down the Pokemon GO app completely

It looks like your phone is *stuck* on that particular app.